# Waiting for React component state to update before testing with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component with a `handleAdd` function. This function calls a library, which in turn calls `axios` and returns a promise. Once that's resolved, the `handleAdd()` method updates component state which in turns renders child(ren).

In other words, it checks with the server first to make sure the item is added before displaying it locally.

When testing with Jest, i have to await sleep for a few msec before the expect runs otherwise the shallow render isn't updated yet, even though I mock/overwrite the api call. There's some delay between the promise resolving, rerender and expect(). Here's what that kind of looks like:

```
it('adds a thing', async () => {
    ThingManager.default.addPlan = () => {
      const response = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { resolve() })
      return response;
    }

    const wrapper = shallow(<Home />)
    wrapper.find('button').simulate('click')
    const input = wrapper.find('#plan-title')
    input.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'TEST ITEM' } })

    await sleep(500) // without it, <Thing /> isn't rendered yet.

    expect(wrapper.find('Thing').length).toBe(1)
  });
```

What's the proper way of doing this?

Comment: The question is very specific to the lib you're using that seems to be Enzyme. Consider specifying this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wanted to throw it out there that I use simple `setTimeout` with the combination of jest's `done()`.

**EDIT**

```
it('sample test case', (done) => {
        // initialize your component

        setTimeout(function () {
            // expect something that's available after the timeout
            done();
        }, 500);
    });
```

Comment: newbie here. Can you please share an example?

Comment: @NandanPhadke I've added an edit

Comment: Waiting some arbitrary amount of time for some non deterministic event to happen is usually a bad solution.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`act`](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act) from `test-utils`. That is what the React docs recommend, but I have had more success with [`waitFor`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async) from `testing-library`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an enzyme user, but I do use jest. Here is how I do this with @testing-library/react. The recommendation is that you don't look at the state directly, but at the markup resulting from the state being set.

```js
const view = render(<Thing />);
const input = await screen.findByTestId('input-test-id');
fireEvent.change(input, {
  target: {value: 'new value'},
});
// This element is then displayed as a result of the state getting set
// resulting from the change event. screen.findByTestId (or any screen.find*) waits for 
// the element to appear timing out if it does not.
expect(await screen.findByTestId('logo-image-test-id')).toBeDefined();
```