# How do I wait for the user.click() in testing-library React to update the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, testing-library

https://codesandbox.io/p/github/Lir-kulikov/users/main?file=%2Fsrc%2F__tests__%2FApp.test.js&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A22%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A21%2C%22startColumn%22%3A22%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A21%7D%5D

In codesandbox in src/tests/App.test.js the trivial tests fail because after simulated click (line 21) `screen.getByRole` is triggered before the state is updated. To make sure you can uncomment the function with `await` on line 21. It will make everything work ok. How to fix it correctly following best practices?

And second question: in all tests, even those which pass ok, I get error with act (you can see it in sandbox too). When I have tried to wrap it into `act()`, eslint started swearing and it didn't help anyway. I've read various articles on the subject, but still didn't understand what's wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63326272/waiting-for-react-component-state-to-update-before-testing-with-jest

Comment: It helps me to use await findByRole() instead of getByRole() and it works. Thanks! But I'm not sure that is the best way.  And I also have a problem with the "act()" warning :(

Comment: `await act( async () => { await findByRole() })` should get rid of the act warnings. Only use it when the action is supposed to change the state.

Comment: Sorry for that. I've fixed it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252225/discussion-between-tao-and-lirrr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```js
import { waitFor } from '@testing-library/react'

// ...
await waitFor(async () => await user.keyboard("Joe@gmail.com"));
```

See it working [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/Lir-kulikov/users/csb-97nzg4/draft/nostalgic-dawn?file=%2Fsrc%2F__tests__%2FApp.test.js&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A67%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A19%2C%22startColumn%22%3A2%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A19%7D%5D).

---

<strike>But I still think there should be a better way.</strike>

Technically, `user.keyboard` doesn't return a promise, so the `async/await` should not be necessary. But when I remove them, I get an `Avoid using side effects within waitFor` warning. <sup>***1***</sup>

---

<sup>***1***</sup> - No longer true for `@testing-library/user-event@^14`, fixed in [react-testing-library/issues/1137](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/1137), see @Lirrr's comment below.

Comment: It looks like a bug which fixed in the 14 version. And unfortunately, when we install @testing-library/user-event we still get version 13.5 with this bug. https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/1125

Comment: npm install @testing-library/user-event@latest makes user events as promise and it works like a charm.